# Como hacer un update o insert dependiendo de una consulta en un mismo query en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqldb

Buenas tengo una tabla que se llama Socio en esta tabla tengo los campo IDSocio(primary key auto incrementable),Nombre,Apellido,NumeroDocumento lo que quiero hacer es que si ya existe el NumeroDocumento en la tabla haga un update y si no existe que haga un insert, pero no se como hacerlo alguien me pude indicar como?

Comment: Hay que pegarse una vuelta por la documentación... [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: el problema es que IDSocio es auto incrementable y es la primary key entonces no tengo como saber ese dato solo necesito saber es con el campo NumeroDocumento

Comment: Te recomiendo antes de insertar consultes si el registro existe y depende del resultado con un IF insertas o actualices..